# Testing Amazon EC2, RDS and ELB performance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, load-testing, performance-testing, amazon-rds

I have a PHP application which I have running on Amazon's Web Services. It's a relatively simple PHP script which basically does a simple write to an SQL database. This Database is an Xtra Large RDS instance. The PHP is running on a large EC2 instance behind a load balancer.

What I would like to do is to stress test my script to simulate about 800 users all connected at the same time (yes, that truely is the estimate).

I have heard about Siege, but I wasn't sure how to go about using it to test my application. If I try running it from my connection at home, I'm not sure that my PC / ADSL is even fast enough to create enough traffic to simulate 800 users attacking the EC2s (thus the RDS) all at once.

Is it advisable to start another EC2 instance in another zone to simply "Siege" my application? Or perhaps running 2 EC2 instances, both sieging with 400 users each!?

One hope that this would test the load balancing, the RDS and the EC2s thoroughly.

Does anyone have experience with this kind of high-concurrent-user testing?

Andy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a script that might help with what you need, details [here](http://www.http503.com/2012/run-jmeter-on-amazon-ec2-cloud/), source [here](https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2).

But first of all, and really, this is the most important thing, you need to consider what defines a 'user'. Whilst it might seem obvious in descriptive terms, in technical terms you need to start to talk about requests per second.

Now that bug bear is out of the way, to run load tests against Amazon using ELBs there's a couple of things you might want to know about.

1. At this sort of load you'll very likely need to ask Amazon to 'pre-warm' things. Last time I looked into this I found that an ELB is essentially a software load balancer running on a simple instance. Like all things, these instances have a throughput limit and tend to max out at around (very vague) 40 requests a second. They will autoscale but the algorithm for this is not suited to load testing so pre warming is Amazon spinning up X ELBs beforehand where X is based on the information you provide to them in your request (see my first point around requests per second, not users).
2. ELBs can cache DNS which in load testing can cause issues. If your test tool is java based (like JMeter) use: -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=0

Whatever solution you opt for, be very aware that your test itself can become the bottleneck, you should check for this first before blaming the application you're testing.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of cloud based load testing services available including

http://blazemeter.com
http://www.neustar.biz/enterprise/web-performance

They can get quite expensive, but then again, so can spinning up a number of ec2 instances to test from (plus your engineering time).

Answer (score 2):

Don't give up on Siege yet. It is simple but very powerful load test tool. The basic usage example may be:

```
siege -d 1 -c 10 http://url
```

Which will simulate 10 simultaneous connections (users) making request about every 1 second. 
If the size of your HTTP request and responses are small enough then you may be good - even using your DSL connection. Siege will show you statistics, including the average response size, so you should be able to easily estimate what your limits are. If sizes are to big for your connection, the idea of using separate EC2 instances will definitely work well. Probably one instance would suffice, but you may have to increase the file descriptors limit on the machine that's runing siege (otherwise you will run out of them):

```
sysctl -w fs.file-max=100000
```

If you would like to test with multiple URLs you can put them in a text file and tell siege to use it as targets:

```
siege -d 1 -c 800 -i -t 2m -f urls.txt
```

will emulate 800 users making request every 1 second for 2 minutes. URLs will be randomly selected (-i) from the urls.txt file.

I would recommend running couple of tests, increasing the number of connections gradually.

You should get nice statistics when it finishes or you terminate it manually with ctrl+C.
You WILL have to request ELB prewarming with AWS support if the test will generate much more traffic than you currently have. ELBs are slow to scale the throughput in response to traffic spikes.

By default Siege uses HTTP 1.1 so if your server uses persistent connections - it will work.

Comment: Great tool! I love that you can delay each user to make only 1 per second, this was my problem with ab that it just bombarded the server and crashed it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of tools out there that can generate load from the cloud - which is probably what you want to do (it's a lot easier than setting up your own load engines). Be sure to choose one that can handle DNS load balancing...many cannot handle new DNS entries during a test and therefore don't test ELB application accurately. The suggestion for JMeter above helps, but is still not entirely accurate, since a larger % of VUs will switch to the new IPs as soon as they become available. Real users will stay with the IP they started with and only NEW users will go to the newly added IPs.

I'll pimp our software, which tests ELB sites accurately - [Web Performance Load Tester](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/). You can try out the free version here: http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/free-load-tester-lite.html   and feel free to contact us with any questions.